# automatically inject services net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, startup, webapi

I am doing a project in .net core

and always adding Interfaces and Services implement that Interfaces

```
public interface IDBContainer{
...
}

public class DBContainer : IDBContainer{
...
}
```

and i inject them in the startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddTransient<IDBContainer, DBContainer>();
}
```

or using extension method adding them

```
public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services)
{
       services.AddTransient<IDBContainer, DBContainer>();
       return services;
}
```

and in startup

```
[..]
services.AddInfrastructure();
```

but that is the problem i has to inject each one myself as interface and service

in the extension method or in the startup class

**is there away to add the interface and implementation for it automatically. and there is another thing the interfaces and class is in another project assembly in the same solution???**

and there is no problem to use other library if it can do it like **AutoFac** or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor ?
As far as I know AutoFac can also be used with some extra work documented here https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html

Answer (score 0):

While I personally prefer EXPLICIT IoC registrations.

Here is a "autoscan" library.

NetCore.AutoRegisterDi

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetCore.AutoRegisterDi/

https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/asp-net-core-fast-and-automatic-dependency-injection-setup/

> How to NetCore.AutoRegisterDi works The NetCore.AutoRegisterDi library
> is very simple – it will scan an assembly, or a collection of
> assemblies to find classes that a) are simple classes (not generic,
> not abstract, not nested) that have interfaces and b) have an
> interface(s). It will then register each class with its interfaces
> with the NET Core DI provider.